# Core Data does not save properly

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, xcode11

When I create a Core Data Object and don't close the App everything works as expected, but as soon as I close my app and start it again the title property of the object disappears. Does anyone know why that happens? I have another String stored in Core Data exactly the same way as the title and this one works perfectly.

Comment: Do you save on the managedObjectContext?

Comment: yes `guard let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext else {
                fatalError("Unable to read managed object context.")
            }`

Comment: No, I mean after you make some change to a Core Data object do you `context.save()`? Changes to an object are only persisted into Core Data if you save it.

Comment: Yes, I have a View Model where I have a function called saveContext `func saveContext(){
        if context.hasChanges{
            do{
                try self.context.save()
                getTodos()
                print("all saved")
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Do you call that function? When? Where? Getting debug help is almost impossible if you don’t post the relevant code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I solved the problem already. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Excellent. You are able to post a solution to your own question to help anyone with the same problem.